# How can i pause or cancel a Loop in NodeJs from Angular Client

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I am wondering if it is possible to cancel or pause a loop which runs in NodeJs. In my case i have a function which the User calls via the angular client and kicks of a mail to a list of people.
In NodeJs there is a function that loops over the list and sends the email. I also provide progress via socket.io which all works fine. The question is, is there a way to interrupt, cancel this loop from the client once it is kicked off. 
Below is my code which i currently use to update client of progress etc.

```
campRoutes.post('/sendEmail/:socketid?', token_check, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        // Get Socket info
        const socketid = req.params.socketid

        let emails

        if (req.body.massEmailType == 'Farm') {
            emails = await bulk.getEmails(req.body.tractList)
            let recCount = emails[0].length
            // Calculate the delay timer based on record count

            // If the client send SocketID we will update via socket
            if (socketid) {
                console.log(socketid)
                io.to(`${socketid}`).emit('emailCount', {count: recCount})
            }

            let i = 1
            while (i <= recCount){

            if (socketid) {
                //TODO: Add Email Send Code
                io.to(`${socketid}`).emit('emailProcessed', {count: i})
                io.to(`${socketid}`).emit('massEmailSend', {name : emails[0][i-1].name , address :emails[0][i-1].address})
                console.log('Sending Message ' + emails[0][i-1].address)
                i++
                await sleep(150)
            }

            }

        }


        res.json({ Success: true , Error: "", Message:"", Data:emails})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ Success: false , Error: error.Error, Message:error.Error})  

    }

})
```

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of would be to introduce some boolean flag which would be updated by client emitting event and checked inside of the while loop condition.

Comment: That was my idea as well to set a Boolean of stop and if true exit the loop. But the question is how do i send / emit a event from client which would specifically change that Boolean in the loop ?

Comment: Not sure if it's a good practice, but I'd simply create a separate event, like `stopSendingEmail` and on receiving it simply update that Boolean var. And Boolean var should be declared in an outer scope of the route, so that it's available for both - the route function and event listener.

Comment: What worries me is that if there is multiple users calling this mailSend loop function and someone calls the function to set stop. Will that effect all users or will this be only for the session the current user is using. As nodeJs is stateless i am wondering how to address this that it only impacts the one user

Comment: In the easiest implementation it'd indeed impact all users. To avoid this you might attach that bool var to user somehow. The exact implementation will dependent on the way user sessions are handled in you project.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a loop, I guess you can listen for SIGTERM for your specific pid using

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {...
```

Technique documented in https://hackernoon.com/graceful-shutdown-in-nodejs-2f8f59d1c357

Answer (score -1):

For now i solved this not using socket.io to stop the loop but http.get

- i created a mailStop Array on my controller which the user calls
  to call the Mail Loop function
- after user calls the function I    return via socket.io a
  mailingID which is then set on the angular    client.
- if the user clicks stop process will make a call to api    and
  push the mailingID into the mailStop Array.
- In my loop i check    if the mailingID is in the mailStop Array
  and if it is exit the loop.
- For good housekeeping i remove the mailingID from the mailStop
  Array

This works and will also handle multiple users making call to same function and getting wrong result as each click will have its own mailingId.

Onlything which would be great is to figure out a way how to set this message from client to server via socket.io